# Why does pip install replaces the "git@" part of path with "****@" when trying to install from github repository?

Tags: github, installation, pip

I'm trying to install a certain package from github repository by running

```
pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/username/package.git
```

Result is as following:

```
Collecting git+ssh://****@github.com/username/package.git
  Cloning ssh://****@github.com/username/package.git to /some_local_path/
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q 'ssh://****@github.com/username/package.git' '/some_local_path' Check the logs for full command output.
```

For some reason when pip tries to clone the repository, it replaces the "git@" part with "****@" and obviously can't clone anything. With https everything works, but I have to do it with SSH. What's wrong with it and how to solve the issue?

Comment: Note that neither Git nor ssh are producing the asterisks; that's just for display purposes, as [sinoroc said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65235231/1256452). The `git+ssh://` scheme (the "scheme" is the part up to and including the colon-slash-slash) tells pip to use ssh, not https; if you tell pip to use something else, it should work, or you can just set things up so that you do have ssh access to GitHub.: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

Answer (score 1):

The stars `*` are probably placeholders to hide the credentials (username and/or password). So most likely the stars are not used (passed to the server), but only shown in the input to hide security sensitive credentials.

---

As to why it doesn't work, one explanation is that maybe pip, ssh, and/or git figured out that you have credentials (password) associated with that host (`github.com`) and that username (`git`), maybe via a configuration file somewhere (`pip.conf`, `.git/config`, `.ssh/config`). Those credentials are automatically picked up and added to the URI (passed to the server), but hidden with stars in the console output. And maybe there is something wrong with those credentials, so that the connection (authentication/authorization) fails.

Comment: the part that gets replaced with stars is just the word "git", so I doubt it

Comment: `git` is the username so it is part of the credentials and worth hiding.